# Строгий режим javascript

Tags: javascript

Какие преимущества (или выгоды) дает указание

```
"use strict"
```

в коде javascript?

Comment: кстати, я недавно отвечал на [похожий вопрос][1]

[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/274965/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-jslint-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-use-strict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко: чем строже язык программирования, тем меньше вероятность допустить ошибку и вызвать последующий баг. Строгие режимы позволяют выявлять опасные места вроде глобальных переменных, несоответствия наследников родителям, вызовов несуществующих элементов массивов. На первый взгляд, это просто заставляет разработчика плотнее заниматься вещами, отвлекающими от основной задачи, однако использование строгих режимов, тестов, четкого разбиения логики в системе позволяет либо избежать, либо быстро найти не очень заметные ошибки, которые (вроде того же несуществующего элемента массива в PHP) могут отнять куда больше времени на их поиск, чем написание кода по стандарту. Сам же по себе строгий режим никак не меняет выполнение кода (кроме того, что обрывает его в местах, несоответствующих строгому режиму).

Другими словами, если вам нужно написать одну анимашку на jQuery и strict mode говорит вам, что вы не можете использовать глобальные переменные - проще отключить его, потому что здесь глобальные переменные никому не помешают. Если вы пишете большое и тяжелое приложение, то без всех этих средств в один прекрасный момент вы обнаружите, что на поддержание кода уходит больше времени, чем на написание.

Comment: @Fike, насколько я понял, это тоже самое, когда в пхп пишешь error_reporting? Ну, то есть оповещение о ЛЮБЫХ несоответствиях и ошибках? Это круто.

Comment: В ццелом - да, аналог E_STRICT.